# mysql 3 queries on 2 tables in one

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables that I need to query

```
**tbl_jobs**
jobid | description | someinfo
1        foo          bar
2        fuu          buu


**tbl_invlog**
idinv | jobid | type | ammount
1       1       add    100
2       1       rem     50
3       1       rem     15
4       1       add     8
5       2       add     42
```

the result should be to make a sum of the inventory "add" and "rem" and give a total of sum(add)-sum(rem) for each jobid, including the rest of the job information.

```
jobid | description | someinfo | amountadd | amountrem | totaladdrem
1     | foo         | bar      | 108       | 65        | 43
2     | fuu         | buu      | 42        | 0         | 42
```

i have made a quadruple select statement with select * from (select .... ) without using joins or other cool stuff. which is terribly slow. I am quite new to mysql.

I would be glad to an idea on how to solve this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a query that requires a join and conditional aggregation:

```
select j.jobid, j.description, j.someinfo,
       sum(case when il."type" = 'add' then amount else 0 end) as AmountAdd,
       sum(case when il."type" = 'rem' then amount else 0 end) as AmountRem,
       (sum(case when il."type" = 'add' then amount else 0 end) -
        sum(case when il."type" = 'rem' then amount else 0 end)
       ) as totaladdrem
from tbl_jobs j left outer join
     tbl_invlog il
     on j.jobid = il.jobid
group by j.jobid, j.description, j.someinfo;
```

Note some things.  First, the tables have table aliases, defined in the `from` clause.  This allows you to say which table the columns come from.  Second, the table aliases are always used for all columns in the query.

MySQL would allow you to just do `group by j.jobid`, using a feature called "hidden columns".  I think this is a bad habit (except in a few cases), so this aggregates by all the columns in the jobs table.

The conditional aggregation is done by putting a condition in the `sum()` statement.